# What are some pointers for adjusting printing margins on a webpage, with lots of dynamic elements and no print-friendly version?

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, printing, printer

I am sorry that the title may not reflect what exactly I am trying to ask as I do not know much about website design terminology, so I will try to be as descriptive as I can

The question is about printing out non-printer friendly websites. I understand there may not a generic solution that applies to all websites, so I am looking for a general enough solution, or at least some pointers on what I can try. This is only about printing as a pdf file and I am not concerned about printing on actual paper. I have tried simply saving the page (ctrl+s) which seems to preserve the formatting correctly, but there is something on the page that keeps trying to connect to the internet, and that prevents me from opening the webpage offline (it opens for about 2 seconds, then goes into a DNS error page when opening the saved web page offline)

I am trying to print out this page (using google translate on Chrome to translate from Chinese to English)

https://blog.csdn.net/wzz4420381/article/details/106773005

I have an adblocker on, so a lot of the ads in the margins are already removed. Trying to print it normally (using paper size as A0, the default A4 size is completely messed up) looks like this:

[image]

I notice that some information is cut off in the margins :

**Print preview version**:
[image]

**What this section looks like on the real web page**:
[image]

It's clear that some part of the web page has been cut off. I initially assumed it was because of the print margin settings, but playing around with the margin settings in chrome did not help. Some parts are still cut off in the pdf version. I am now thinking it is probably because of some elements on the web page itself. For Example, in this print preview version of the page,

[image]

the banner inside the box is something that scrolls down as I scroll down on the page, until I reach a certain point in the page (end of the article, which is not the end of the page itself) after which the banner stays at that point even if I scroll further down. In the print version however this banner appears at the end of each page of the pdf. I think elements like these on the web page are what are preventing me from properly printing it out. I have tried basic things I am familiar with (playing around with margin size, changing print paper size, etc) but it's not really helping. I just want the full article as a pdf file so that I can read it offline if I need to. What can I do to print such non-printer-friendly websites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be other options when taking matters into your own hands, but a more quick and painless method would be to simply take advantage of a solution that already exists!

Web services such as [this](https://www.printfriendly.com/) are readily available, and I'd presume it isn't the only one out there.  Just plug in the URL and see if there's any improvement, if not you can just try a different one until you get your desired output.  Hope that helps!

Comment: This worked, thanks. If you could link other similar sties or post some google keywords to search for to get similar sites, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: No problem!  The search term I tried was "print-friendly web service".  It looks like there's plenty to choose from with just that search alone, but you may want to add a "-extension" if you want to filter out Chrome web store extensions from the results.